# My baked textures are mostly black

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

Hello I'm new to baking textures. I have been following a YouTube tutorial to the tee but my textures are bugged and I don't know why.

[image]

It's mostly in black like in the pictures. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots Sure! https://easyupload.io/erg7qq

Comment: Could you check the result with the 'direct' and 'indirect' checkboxes set to off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some clothes on your character, they are hidden for preview but enabled for render and they are blocking any light when you bake, disable them in render as well:

[image]

Comment: It worked! I feel dumb... But thank you sir!